# Move gitlab Project under another Project's Directory

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two existing gitlab projects: projectA with branchA and projectB with branchB. 
I want to move the entire contents of branchA to be under a directory of branchB without losing history of commits if possible.

I tried cloning the two projects to a machine, copying the files from one branch to the other and commiting but then I lost the files history.

How can this be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clone projectB**

```
git clone git clone <projectB repo URL>
```

**Create an empty orphan branch**

```
git checkout --orphan temp_branch
git rm -rf .
```

**Add remote of projectA**

```
git remote add -f projectA  <projectA repo URL>
```

**Merge *temp_branch* with branchA from projectA**

```
git merge projectA/branchA --allow-unrelated-histories
```

*At this point you could move the contents as they are or also rewrite the history to make it seem that these files had always been in a sub folder.*

***NOTE:*** You have to chose one or the other either option 1 or option 2. Then you can continue the rest of the steps normally.

**Move contents of *temp_branch* to sub folder and commit(without rewrite - option 1)**

```
mkdir projectA
git mv -k * projectA/ 
git add .
git commit -m "Move projectA/branchA to sub folder"
```

**Move contents of *temp_branch* to sub folder and commit(with rewrite - option 2)**

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "mkdir projectA;git mv -k * projectA" HEAD
```

**Merge with projectB/branchB**

```
git checkout branchB
git merge temp_branch --allow-unrelated-histories
```

**Delete *temp_branch* and projectA remote**

```
git branch -D temp_branch 
git remote remove projectA
```

**Push to *projectB* remote (make sure you are on branchB)**

```
git checkout branchB
git push origin branchB
```

You should have merged the two while retaining the git history of both branches. Since the histories are unrelated I recommend using option 2 because it rewrites the history in such a way that it seems projectA always existed in its sub folder. Just my opinion though.

***Final NOTE:*** that when moving the files to a sub folder, make sure you move any hidden files accordingly(one by one or all at once), I just used the * to give a simple example but you may have some .(dot) files that need to be moved too. Just make sure not to move the .git folder. I also used git mv instead of mv to ensure compatibility with windows if you are using a windows PC